# Having trouble opening a web application

Tags: web-application

I have a single SharePoint2013 server and I was able to build the Web Application and the Site collection.

When I attempt to open the page i am sent to the "IIS" page.

Answer (score 0):

You must configure [Alternate Access Mapping](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/configure-alternate-access-mappings)

Comment: Ahmed, thank you for your response. If I understand "alternate access mappings" correctly then this feature would allow me to redirect a public URL to a different internal URL.  On my current configuration, my public and private URL are the same.  FYI: I only have one web application with one site collection.